# Can we shrink up widgets when scrolling without Slivers in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to create this crazy layout with 3 widgets on top that should shrink/retract when the user scrolls the page down. But since the elements are dynamic and because I have 2 tabs on the body here, it's not working with Sliver. Is there any other way to shrink/retract these 3 widgets with something other than Slivers?

[image]

Ideally, the "Pick a date" Row and the Tabs should shrink while the "Filter Button" Row should still be visible when the user is scrolling.

Comment: can you please add an image from your layout?

Comment: Sure thing. Image added.

Comment: you could wrap the 'pick a date' row in animated container where the height should be controlled by the amount of scroll position obtained using the scroll controller.

Comment: Hey "Doc", that sounds very promising. Would you be able to help me out with some sample of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you require something like this then follow the below steps.

[image: Video For Demo]

Section and News Stories Widget.

```
class Section extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiSliver(
      pushPinnedChildren: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          ...
        ),
        if (!infinite)
          SliverAnimatedPaintExtent(
            child: SliverList(...),
          )
        else
          SliverList(...),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NewsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        Section(infinite: false),
        Section(infinite: true),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

List Sliver Implementation.

```
class NewsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          Strings.of(context).pages.news.title,
        ),
      ),
      body: View<NewsModel>(
        onModelReady: (model) => model.load(),
        builder: (context, model, _) {
          return Scrollbar(
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
                  onRefresh: () => model.load(),
                ),
                NewsSection(
                  model: model.topStories,
                  infinite: false,
                ),
                NewsSection(
                  model: model.newStories,
                  infinite: true,
                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Complete Implementation can be found here.](https://github.com/Kavantix/hn_state_example)

Comment: Hello Darsh Shah. I can't have Slivers. The idea is to create this "retraction" without any Slivers.